# Styling conditional FlatList?

Tags: react-native

I want to show `FlatList` only if there are results from an `axios` call. Unfortunately when there are some results, they are showing beneath the components below it, like `TextArea`, etc. I tried a lot of styling combinations but nothing works. Any help is appriciated!

```js
const CreateScreen = () => {
  const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState("");
  const [isShowingResults, setIsShowingResults] = useState(false);

  searchLocation = async (text) => {
    setSearchKeyword(text);

    axios
      .request({
        method: "post",
        url:
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=" +
          apiKey +
          "&input=" +
          searchKeyword +
          "&types=(cities)&components=country:bg&language=bg",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);

        setSearchResults(response.data.predictions);

        setIsShowingResults(true);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.response);
      });
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 3 }}>Address</Text>
      <View style={styles.autocompleteContainer}>
        <TextInput
          returnKeyType="search"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={(text) => searchLocation(text)}
          value={searchKeyword}
        />
        {isShowingResults && (
          <FlatList
            data={searchResults}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.resultItem}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setSearchKeyword(item.description);

                    setIsShowingResults(false);
                  }}
                >
                  <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            style={styles.searchResultsContainer}
          />
        )}
      </View>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 3 }}>Title</Text>
        <TextInput />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  autocompleteContainer: {
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  searchResultsContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 50,
  },
  resultItem: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{isShowingResults? (
      <FlatList
        data={searchResults}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.resultItem}
              onPress={() => {
                setSearchKeyword(item.description);

                setIsShowingResults(false);
              }}
            >
              <Text>{item.description}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        style={styles.searchResultsContainer}
      />
    ):null}
```

You can try this, or you can just pass ListEmptyComponent to null, nothing will display when you have empty array in data of flatlist